# Read socket and memorization not working as expected

Tags: c, sockets

I've the following problem with this code:

```
#define success "success"
#define fail "fail"
char *verify = fail;
char b[1024];

int main(){
   ...
   ...connect to server code...
   ...
   read(sock,verify,1024);
   printf("%s",verify); //there's the problem, it always prints fail. If I change with this:
   read(sock,b,1024);
   printf("%s",b); //this works and prints the received string.
}
```

Can you help me to understand? The problem is in this part of this code or should I check elsewhere?

If I do an easy assign in the code like 'verify=success' it seems to works fine, reading from a socked isn't the same as an asisgnation?

Comment: You're writing to read-only memory (the string-literal `"fail"`). I'm shocked this even executes without faulting, unless of course, your socket setup was fail (pun intended) and the resulting `read` was an ignored, error-inducing no-op.

Comment: @WhozCraig damn you've reason, what a stupid question :( Thanks!

Comment: Also, `read()` doesn't create a null-terminated string. You should not use string functions on its input buffer.

Comment: @Barmar If I define the string success in the server too, and I send it to the client, and I read it with read(), and then I strcmp(success,b), this should work fine, right? Also, If I send a null terminated string from the server to the client, this should be memorized in b as a null terminated string, right?

Comment: No. If this is a stream socket, there are no message boundaries. `read()` might not return everything that was written in one call, you might have to loop to get it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to read from the socket into the memory area pointed by `verify`, which is `"fail"`.
In C the expression `"fail"` allocates 5 bytes in read-only memory, fills them with `{'f','a','i','l','\0'}` in compile time and returns its address.

So you're trying to overwrite read-only memory. I'm wondering why you don't get a segmentation fault. Did you check the return value of `read`? It might be a kernel-side sanity check within `read` which prevents it from attempting to write into RO memory.

In the second `read` call, it's OK, because `b` points to the start of the array variable, which is writable.

You're actually confusing yourself with your own coding style: defining `fail`, which looks like a variable, does not make it a variable. The C preprocessor just replaces it and you end up with

```
char *verify = "fail";
```